# Camera Helper Three Fiber

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm trying to add a camera helper to visualize what my camera sees.  I found a storybook from Drei that shows how to use useHelper, but I'm not seeing it show up.  Any tips?

Story: https://drei.pmnd.rs/?path=/story/gizmos-usehelper--camera-story

Github: https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/blob/050c2abcfdc00fe455326567533fefffad179da8/.storybook/stories/useHelper.stories.tsx

My own Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/visible-width-camera-helper-ycsxjn?file=/src/App.js

I may be wrong but my thinking was that I should be able to see the perspectiveCamera from Fiber's default camera.

```
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { PerspectiveCamera, useHelper, CameraHelper, OrbitControls, Box } from '@react-three/drei'
import { useRef } from 'react'

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas tonemapped={'false'}>
      <color attach="background" args={['#fff']} />
      <OrbitControls />
      <Experience />
    </Canvas>
  )
}

const Experience = () => {
  const camera = useRef()
  useHelper(camera, CameraHelper)
  return (
    <>
      <ambientLight intensity={1} />
      <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault={false} ref={camera} near={1} far={4} position={[0, 0, 0]}>
        <meshBasicMaterial />
      </PerspectiveCamera>
      <Box />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `THREE.Camera` instead of `CameraHelper` from `@react-three/drei`

code like

```
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { PerspectiveCamera, useHelper, CameraHelper, OrbitControls, Box } from '@react-three/drei'
import { useRef } from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three'

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas tonemapped={'false'}>
      <color attach="background" args={['#fff']} />
      <OrbitControls />
      <Experience />
    </Canvas>
  )
}

const Experience = () => {
  const camera = useRef()
  useHelper(camera, THREE.CameraHelper)
  return (
    <>
      <ambientLight intensity={1} />
      <PerspectiveCamera ref={camera} near={1} far={4} position={[0, 0, 0]}></PerspectiveCamera>
      <mesh>
        <boxGeometry />
        <meshBasicMaterial color="red" />
      </mesh>
    </>
  )
}
```

I adjusted [your Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/visible-width-camera-helper-forked-yq2803?file=/src/App.js:0-747)